# How to config quill editor support markdown syntax as one in gitlab?

Tags: javascript, markdown, quill

Current, I have a quill editor supporting markdown that look like this

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow'
});
new QuillMarkdown(quill)

quill.on('text-change', function(delta, oldDelta, source) {
  document.getElementById("ql").value = quill.root.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<!-- Markdown extension -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quilljs-markdown@latest/dist/quilljs-markdown.js"></script>

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="ql" name="ql"></input>
```

It looks fine, however, I tried to config it to work as this as in gitlab https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mde-latest-5i5ov?file=/src/index.js with no avail as it is reactjs instead pure javascript as mine.

THow can config my current quill editor to look and function as that above? Thanks

Comment: check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/quilljs-markdown

Comment: @Robert, thanks, however, I want my quill editor to look and work exact same like this one  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mde-latest-5i5ov?file=/src/index.js

Comment: i don't get you. If you want that your editor look like mde why you just use it ? Quill have different look, why put so much effort to customize it to look like mde. Just use mde https://simplemde.com/

Comment: https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor only thing you have to do is customize your toolbar icon array by adding what you  need with 'preview' icon.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for suggestion I like that. Let me experience with it, and consider using it. Thanks :)